# NoSQL (e.g. MongoDB) or RDMS (e.g. PostgreSQL) for new Scala project?

Tags: scala, mongodb, architecture, scalaquery, casbah

I'm developing a brand new project in Scala. It's just an application for a bunch of CRUD operations, however, because of some eccentric requirements, Play2 or Lift does not fit the bill, so I'm going to develop the application from the ground up. This means that Anorm or ScalaQuery becomes less obvious choices for database integration, and leaves me with the question: is it time to try something new?

My past technology stacks mostly included Java and PostgreSQL and I have experience with both ORM and plain SQL. Are NoSQL database management systems like MongoDB a good replacement for a typical RDBMS or are they special case application data stores? Also, how does the choice of database effect the greater Scala system design (if at all)? For example, the fact that you are using a JSON-like interface to talk to the database, and JSON between the web and a REST service, does not mean that much if everything in the middle becomes Scala objects, or does it?

I'm basically asking for someone's experience on moving from relational to object/document type databases, using Scala in particular. I know that good RDBMS integration is promised in the upcoming release of SLICK. So, if a company like TypeSafe decides to make a RDBMS integration part of the TypeSafe stack, then will I be swimming upstream by integrating to MongoDB using Casbah for example?

Apologies if this question appears a bit vague. I do hope that someone with the right insights or experience will be able to help though.

*Update:*

Apologies for not adding links to SLICK (it being fairly new). Here goes:

- [Quick overview](http://days2012.scala-lang.org/node/390)
- [Project home](https://github.com/slick/slick)

Update 2:

My personal first win for a technology is usually *developer productivity* - this translates to lightweight and simple: quick to learn, easy to maintain, no magic

Comment: Btw, thanks for mentioning SLICK, I didn't know about it.

Comment: Slick is the former "scalaquery" soon included in typesafe stack

Comment: What did you decide?  How did it go?

Comment: @ballmw I ended up using Slick with PostgreSQL. Documentation on Slick is a little thin, but it's getting better. There are easier options than Slick, and Slick's error messages are currently quite cryptic, but it gives you tons of freedom and allows you to compose complex queries from simpler ones, which is a big win. It's a solid solution. I'm happy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am currently in a similar situation, and since I have some experience with web development and SQL databases, I took it as an opportunity to work with MongoDB, Cashbah (and [Scalatra](http://www.scalatra.org/)). My experience is still very limited and the project and the amount of data I am working with is pretty small, but here are a few observations I've made.

- For the few sets of data I have, performance does not seem to motivate either SQL or NoSQL. However, performance in the presence of huge amounts of data is often listed as a reason for using NoSQL, e.g., [by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)
- My documents (entries in the database) arise from benchmarking test suits, and mainly have a static structure, and I am optimistic that I could store them in a fixed-schema SQL database. However, a few substructures are not static, e.g., new test cases are added, new statistics are tracked, others are removed. This was my main motivation for trying a schema-free NoSQL database. Also, because I had the feeling that the document approach of MongoDB makes it much more obvious which data belongs together (i.e., to a document), in contrast to entries in a relational database, where the data would be distributed over various tables and rows, and where a full "document" would need to be reconstructed by joins.
- Tools such as [Lift-Json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/) or [Rogue](https://github.com/foursquare/rogue) allow you to work with regular Scala objects in a type-safe, although the data is regularly (de-)serialised as (from) JSON. However, this naturally works best if the structure of your data is mainly static, otherwise, you you are left with using strings to access your data (e.g., for expanding the results of a query using Cashbah).

If you are mainly concerned about a coherent representation of data on server and client side, languages such as [Opa](http://www.opalang.org/) or [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) might be of interest, since they compile to code that can executed on both sides. See [this page](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) for "multitarget" or "tierless" languages.

Comment: Some valid points, thank you. On your third point, I get the feeling that one kind of has to trade of one of the actual reasons for going to non-relational in the first place if you want to remain type-safe. Is type-safety and dynamic structure a difficult match?

Comment: Let's assume that your data is of a partially static structure, e.g. {x: _, y: _, z: {a: _, b: _}}, where x, y, z are the only top-level elements and their existence is guaranteed, but the structure of z is not static. If so, you can try to find a sweet spot by using (case) classes where the static parts of the structure is mapped to fields of concrete types (Int, String, etc.), and those with an unknown structure are mapped to Map[String, Any]. The mapping can be done via Lift-Json or Roque.

Answer (score 3):

Got too long for a comment. Was just trying to relate my short experience with Scala (about 6 months now, since about when Play2 came out--it's quickly become my go to language).

I've enjoyed using Salat/Casbah with MongoDB in my last few projects; most have been in Play2, but the latest was without a webapp framework. It definitely hasn't felt like swimming upstream.

I would say that there are particular use cases for which I wouldn't use mongo, but it works nicely as a general purpose object data store, especially if you expect to query by id or index and don't need transactions (and will need minimal ad-hoc aggregation type stuff).

Expect to require a separate set of servers dedicated to mongodb (or to use a service dedicated to mongodb), but I guess that's normal for most serious database apps.

I've also used Play2/Anorm, which was surprisingly enjoyable to use for some ad-hoc query dashboard-style report pages. I started trying to go the Squeryl route, but Anorm seemed easier to use for one-off aggregation queries. Haven't looked at SLICK, but it sounds interesting.

Comment: I appreciate the input (long comment ;-), thanks. Interesting that you mentioned a dedicated server. Hardware resources is something one easily shrugs off these days, but sometimes it may be a real concern.

Comment: Well, I host small LAMP stuff on one box, which tends to keep chugging, but even for small things I'd say make sure you have a dedicated mongo; It doesn't like to share RAM in a manageable way. I still love using it, but I've had it kill my apache box more than once (eventually had to move it off to its own replica set, which is better in the long run, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to say without knowing what problems you would like the app to solve.

I've personally found my productivity increased using NoSQL DBs via REST/JSON.  Though bear in mind most NoSQL DBs offer REST interfaces which preclude the need for much middleware, Scala or otherwise, unless you intend to write a webapp with a UI.

If this is a learning exercise, I recommend you try multiple things out, as each NoSQL DB has something different to offer to your toolkit, and have personally found CouchDB, Riak, Neo4j, and MongoDb all with various pluses and drawbacks and good for different purposes.

Hope this helps, good luck.